# execute multiple elastic search queries at once in java

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch

I know a way to execute a single "search query" in Java. But is there a way to execute more than one elastic search "search queries" in Java, which are independent ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Multi Search Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-msearch.html).According to documentation

> The multi search API allows to execute several search requests within the same API